# Mixing video streams with a fade transition effect myself

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming

I would like to make a a software setup that would let the user switch between two webcam feeds (or more but let's consider two). I would like a fade in/out effect while switching. My main problem is that I don't know how to start.

There seems to be some ffmpeg tool that could do the job (like libavfilter) but I don't get how I could setup it.

What should I consider to use if I want to access frame image to make the transition myself? Is there some simpler way?

I know that this question looks really poorly written, but I'm as lost as I look.

Comment: What platform should this software run on? Web? Mobile? Desktop? If desktop, what OS? On Linux, I'd look at gstreamer.

Comment: Linux for my system yes but I would like to stream the output to anything.

Comment: FFmpeg has the [blend](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#blend) filter which has [timeline](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Timeline-editing) support. I'm not sure of the best way to do this "on demand" though.

Comment: GStreamer should do that. I think that's what Landell uses too:  http://landell.holoscopio.com/